# How to work on an object to which I added an event listener?

Tags: jquery, event-listener

I have a problem with an event listener. Every time when I want to work on element I added event listener to I'm geting **error**, and no,

> $(this).css('background-color','red');

not working.

code:

```
$('#test').dblclick({$('#test').css('background-color','red');});
```

error:
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string*

Comment: $('#test').dblclick(() => {$('#test').css('background-color','red');});

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You forgot the `function` part of your function: `$('#test').dblclick(function () {$('#test').css('background-color','red');});`

Comment: Start here: [jquery events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/) and compare your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide a function as argument of dblclick :

```js
    $('#test').dblclick(() => {$('#test').css('background-color','red');});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is **solution** to your question.

```
$("#test").on({
    dblclick: function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
```

Kindly try this solution.

Comment: This just looks like you took someone else's comment and made it into an answer, on a question that's clearly just a typo.

Comment: It is not copied from anywhere, Just answered the question to user requirement.